# How to create memory-based disk in linux?

Tags: linux, memory, disk

I need to have a very fast disk for keeping cache. How can I do that in Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Mat:

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/ram
# mount -t ramfs -o size=20m ramfs /mnt/ram
```